# How did the Early Church Fathers view homosexuality?

Tags: old-testament, early-church, new-testament, homosexuality

How did the Early Church Fathers view the act of homosexuality, did they condemn it or did they interrupt the verses differently than we do, verses such as:

> You shall not lie with a male as with a woman. It is an abomination.

**Leviticus 18:22**

> 9 Do you not know that the unrighteous will not inherit the kingdom of
> God? Do not be deceived. Neither fornicators, nor idolaters, nor
> adulterers, nor homosexuals, nor sodomites, 10 nor thieves, nor
> covetous, nor drunkards, nor revilers, nor extortioners will inherit
> the kingdom of God.

**1 Corinthians 6:9-10**

> 26 For this reason God gave them up to vile passions. For even their
> women exchanged the natural use for what is against nature. 27
> Likewise also the men, leaving the natural use of the woman, burned in
> their lust for one another, men with men committing what is shameful,
> and receiving in themselves the penalty of their error which was due.

**Romans 8:9-10**

Comment: They didn’t think in terms of  homosexuality which is just a small segment of sodomy, they addressed the whole umbrella term, sodomy, the act of anal or oral intercourse between, hetero or homosexuals married or unmarried, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Mike Wenger has a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxw4I5nQs84) on what the Bible says. (Link is to the NT part; the other three parts are also recommended.) I would count Peter and Paul as "early church fathers".

Comment: @Autodidact Is there an answer from you in our future?

Comment: @MikeBorden why do you ask?

Comment: @Autodidact I ask because I have seen various definitions of sodomy and you sound as though you may have done some research.

Comment: @MikeBorden I’ve yet to find a dictionary 19th century or older that doesn’t define sodomy as anal AND fellatio. The word homosexuality is a diversion

Comment: @Autodidact Does the word sodomy or sodomite appear in Scripture?

Comment: קדשׁה And קדשׁ in the OT. It is understood from history what qualified a person to be a sodomite. This is systematically being erased by those who are offended at the truth @MikeBorden

Comment: @Autodidact Those two words seem to come from roots denoting unfaithfulness.  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97396/difference-between-%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-and-

Comment: @Autodidact  Looks like Benedictus Levita broadened the meaning for sodomy to all sexual acts not related to procreation that were therefore deemed counter nature around 850AD while still emphasizing all interpersonal acts not taking place between human men and women.  The primarily sexual meaning of the word sodomia for Christians did not evolve before the 6th century AD though Philo (20BC-50AD) and Josephus (96 AD) did describe Sodom's sin in terms of homosexuality.

Comment: @MikeBorden that’s primarily because heterosexuals in antiquity didn’t engage in sodomizing each other, be that anal or oral. You say he broadened, that presupposes a prejudicial stance on the matter, he merely stated the obvious. If the only distinction between a heterosexual couple and a homosexual couple is partner choice, then there is nothing wrong with sodomy in and of itself. At which point you might as well make them exclusive and monogamous and let them continue on their merry way. Heb13:4 states that there is a possibility that heterosexual monogamous couples can be immoral in bed

Comment: @Autodidact Some manuscript bases (TR, for example) do not have the imperative and render Hebrews 13:4 as "Marriage is honourable in all, and the bed undefiled" rather than "Let marriage be held in honor among all, and let the marriage bed be undefiled."

Comment: @Autodidact The word translated sexually immoral (ESV) or whoremonger (KJV) namely πορνος (pornos), also means seller or trafficker, but a male one.  Since sex among men was very common in the classical world, our word πορνος (pornos) obviously does not simply describe a male prostitute. As with the feminine version, the emphasis is on the mercantile aspect, and the sex is implied.

Comment: I think we are done @MikeBorden I don’t have the interest nor the time to continue. Beyond that there is the practical aspect, whether one’s relationship with God remains neutral, positive or negative as a consequence of practicing anal and/or oral sex in whatever context and ALL situations show God abhors it even if men find “technical” ways of justifying their abominable practices.

Answer (score 1):

The early church fathers opposed homosexual intercourse.

From *The Encyclopedia of Early Christianity*:

> The church fathers universally condemned male homosexual
> behavior...They clearly regarded it as contrary to the created
> constitution and function of men and women...All the evidence
> indicates that the teaching mind of the early church unreservedly
> condemned homosexual activity (as quoted in Callister *The Inevitable
> Apostasy* p. 214)

Polycarp (writing early 2nd century) paraphrased Peter & Paul in the fifth chapter of his *Epistle to the Philippians*:

> In like manner, let the young men also be blameless in all things,
> being especially careful to preserve purity, and keeping themselves
> in, as with a bridle, from every kind of evil. For it is well that
> they should be cut off from the lusts that are in the world, since
> every lust wars against the spirit; and neither fornicators...nor
> abusers of themselves with mankind, shall inherit the kingdom of God

Note that Polycarp speaks against sexual immorality whether it is hetero- or homosexual.

In Cyprian's *Epistle to Donatus* (see Epistle 1.1.8-10, written mid 3rd century), he speaks out against sexual sin including lust, adultery, incest, emasculation, homosexuality, and prostitution.

They understood the Jewish & Christian texts to oppose homosexual activity, and quoted them as such.

Comment: The word homosexuality is a modern translation preference, sodomy is the correct term and this does not limit it to homo- relationships but includes hetero- too who practice sodomy. The early church would have been just as firm against a married husband and wife practicing sodomy, as two male strangers engaging in sodomy. It’s still sodomy. Narrowing it down to homosexuality doesn’t excuse sodomy for married couples.

Comment: “Let marriage be held in honor among all, and let the marriage bed be undefiled, for God will judge the sexually immoral and adulterous.”
‭‭Hebrews‬ ‭13:4‬ ‭sexually immoral AND adulterous, there are things that even within marriage are immoral. And the NT early church made it clear that this was not limited to homosexual intercourse only but within marriage too

Comment: @Autodidact I suspect quite a few questions could be asked regarding the early church's understanding of chastity-my response focuses specifically on the matter raised in the OP.

Comment: I suppose early church fathers ought to be defined or at least what time period is in question. Fair point